# Multiple annotations found error comes when adding dependency in pom.xml while creating spring, hibernate with maven

Tags: hibernate, spring, maven

I am creating a sample project with maven for spring and hibernate. I am very new to this development. After placing the dependency such as

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupid>org.hibernate</groupid>
        <artifactid>hibernate-core</artifactid>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupid>org.springframework</groupid>
        <artifactid>spring</artifactid>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
```

In eclipse it gives an error as Multiple annotations found at this line:

```
- Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.groupId' for null:null:jar is 
 missing.
- Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.artifactId' for null:null:jar is 
 missing.
```

I guess, the jar files for spring and hibernate are missing. Can someone let me know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because your `pom.xml` has the invalid format

It should be

- `<groupId>` instead of `<groupid>`
- `<artifactId>` instead of `<artifactid>`

You can check the correct format of `pom.xml` at [here](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies)

Comment: My error because of using `<groupID>` and `<artifcatID>`